# open terminal window with python via java on different platforms

Tags: java, python, terminal, cross-platform, runtime.exec

From a Java application I try to open a terminal/cmd window with a python session started and some code from a python file already executed.

For Mac, the following call works nicely:
The file (let's call it hello_world.py) may look like this

```
#! /usr/bin/python -i

print 'Hello, world!'
```

The Java call is the following:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("open -a Terminal hello_world.py");
```

But I don't know how this could be implemented for Windows.

I tried:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /k python hello_world.py");
```

But this will just execute the script but not opening a python session.
Is it possible at all? Can anybody help?

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process.

Comment: I will give that a look - thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was successful with the following call:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {
+                       "cmd",
+                       "/k",
+                       "start",
+                       "python",
+                       "-i",
+                       "hello_world.py"
+               });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd start python hello_world.py");`

Comment: this does throw the following error: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "start": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Forgot to mention cmd at the beginning of the string